# sed - substitute either of two characters with one command

Tags: sed

I would like one `sed` command to accomplish the following:

```
$ sed s'/:/ /g' <and> sed s'/=/ /g'
```

That is, I would like to write

```
sed s'/<something>/ /g'
```

and have both `=` and `:` replaced by space.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
sed s'/[:=]/ /g'
```

Brackets mean "any one of".

Comment: what is the `s'` why not `s`?

Comment: Good question; if you have spaces within one argument of a `bash` command, `bash` will split it into two arguments. We want the whole command to be sent to `sed` as a single argument. You could equally put the quote before the `s`, ie `sed 's/[:=]/ /g'` I think, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Also, if you're escaping a special character, make sure to escape it - for example, I was escaping { and }, that's [\{\}]

Answer (score 10):

One option is also to use `sed -e`, like this. Although you don't need it in this case, it's however a good option to know about.

```
sed -e 's/:/ /' -e 's/..../ /' file
```

Comment: I don't see an equal sign `=` anywhere?

Answer (score 6):

Sanjay's answer solves it. Another option that works with only one sed command is to separate each `s` substitution with a semicolon

```
sed 's/:/ /g ; s/=/ /g' file
```

or in separate lines in a script

```
sed 's/:/ /g 
     s/=/ /g' file
```

Those may be handy in other situations.